# Filter out files in 3 levels hierarchy

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-files, azure-file-share

I'm using the ***Azure File Share* API** to retrieve files stored in a 3 levels hierarchy `/<user>/<machine>/<datafile>`:

```
+
|
+- albert
   |
   +--- pc1
   |    |
   |    +--- 20010101.dat
   |    |
   |    +--- 20010101.dat
  ...  ...
   |    |
   |    +--- 20231001.dat
   +--- pc2
+- james
+- john
```

I'm looking for files at a specific date, so iterating over users and machines folders:

```
foreach (var userFolder in rootFolder.GetSubdirectoriesClients())
{
    foreach (var machineFolder in userFolder.GetSubdirectoriesClients())
    {
        var dataFileName = $"{date:yyyyMMdd}.dat";

        var dataFileItem = machineFolder.GetFilesAndDirectories(new ShareDirectoryGetFilesAndDirectoriesOptions { Prefix = dataFileName }).SingleOrDefault();

        if (dataFileItem != null)
        {
            // Process file
        }
```

All is working fine for some time and then all of a sudden the call to `machineFolder.GetFilesAndDirectories` freezes and after 1min40s (100s) I get a `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException` with message "*The operation was canceled*.".

But it is caught somewhere in between and does not bubble up to my code, and the process continues, managing to do more API calls, then freezes again.

Maybe I could avoid this issue by making less or different API calls.
Ideally I would get the whole list of files from the root in a single call, then prune it to keep only the files I want, but I've not seen such API entry-point.

(Note that this is already my second attempt, the first one being with:

```
var dataFile = machineFolder.GetFileClient(dataFileName);

if (dataFile.Exists())
{
    // ...
}
```

Same issue but on the call to `Exists` instead.)